# $\int_0^1 \frac{|x-\alpha|^{1/2}}{|x-\beta|^{1/2}} dx\ge C\int_0^1 \frac{1}{|x-\beta|^{1/2} }dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality, definite-integrals

> Prove there is a positive constant $C$ such that $\displaystyle\int_0^1
>  \dfrac{|x-\alpha|^{1/2}}{|x-\beta|^{1/2}} dx\ge C\displaystyle\int_0^1
>  \frac{1}{|x-\beta|^{1/2}}dx$ holding for any $\alpha,\beta$.

Denote

$$f(\alpha,\beta)=\displaystyle\int_0^1
 \dfrac{|x-\alpha|^{1/2}}{|x-\beta|^{1/2}} dx,~~~~g(\beta)=\displaystyle\int_0^1
 \frac{1}{|x-\beta|^{1/2}}dx.$$

If $g(\beta)=0$, the conclusion holds simply. Otherwise, we may prove $$\frac{f(\alpha,\beta)}{g(\beta)}\ge C>0.$$

Indeed, we may obtain $$0<g(\beta)\le 2\sqrt{2}.$$
How to go on?

Comment: Using the inequality on g that you derived and using integration by parts on f. You may be able to get something. I can be absolutely wrong too.

Comment: $g(\beta) = 0$ is not possible. – Where does the inequality come from?

Comment: @TeresaLisbon the function $1/\sqrt x$ is integrable, so RHS has a finite maximum in $\beta$.

Comment: @UmbertoP. Thanks for the clarification, I got it.

Comment: *Hint*: I'll assume you only want $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$ and not $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{C}$.  For $\beta$ away from $[0,1]$, you have $\lvert x-\beta\rvert\asymp\lvert\beta\rvert$ for $x\in[0,1]$ uniformly.  Also if $x-\alpha$ is bounded away from $0$ we are good, so only need to check for say $(\alpha,\beta)\in[-1,2]^2$ which is easy enough if $f,g$ are continuous nonzero, which they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to assume you want to settle the question for $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$. Given some $\beta\in\mathbb{R}$, let us find the value(s) of $\alpha$ which minimize(s) the integral $\int_{0}^{1}|\alpha-x|^{1/2}|x-\beta|^{-1/2}\,dx$. As a preliminary step it is pretty relevant to compute $\int_{0}^{1}|x-\beta|^{-1/2}\,dx$:

$$\int_{0}^{1}|x-\beta|^{-1/2}\,dx=R(\beta)=\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}2(\sqrt{\beta}+\sqrt{1-\beta})&\text{if}&\beta\in[0,1]\\2(\sqrt{1-\beta}-\sqrt{-\beta})&\text{if}&\beta \leq 0\\2(\sqrt{\beta}-\sqrt{\beta-1})&\text{if}&\beta \geq  1\end{array}\right. $$
$R(\beta)$ is a continuous, positive, unimodal function. It is symmetric with respect to $\beta=\frac{1}{2}$, where $R$ attains its maximum value $2\sqrt{2}$. It converges to zero like $\frac{1}{\sqrt{|\beta|}}$ when $|\beta|\to +\infty$ and it is differentiable everywhere except at the inflection points with vertical tangents occuring at $\beta=0$ and $\beta=1$. Let us assume $\beta\geq\frac{1}{2}$ without loss of generality. The continuous function

$$ L(\alpha,\beta) = \int_{0}^{1}|\alpha-x|^{1/2} |x-\beta|^{-1/2}\,dx $$
is clearly decreasing over $\alpha\in(-\infty,0)$ and increasing over $\alpha\in(1,+\infty)$. It follows that for a fixed $\beta$ the point(s) of minimum of $L(\alpha,\beta)$ occur(s) for $\alpha\in[0,1]$. In the case $\beta\geq 1$ we have

$$ L(\alpha,\beta)=\int_{0}^{\alpha}\frac{\sqrt{\alpha-x}}{\sqrt{\beta-x}}\,dx + \int_{\alpha}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{x-\alpha}}{\sqrt{\beta-x}}\,dx $$
which can be computed in a explicit way with a bit of patience and/or the help o a CAS. We have

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial\alpha} L(\alpha,\beta) = \operatorname{arctanh}\sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}}-\frac{1}{2}\arctan\left(\frac{2\sqrt{1-\alpha}\sqrt{\beta-1}}{(\beta-1)-(1-\alpha)}\right)$$

which is increasing over $(0,1)$ and with a unique zero to the right of the point $\alpha=\frac{1}{2}$. Unluckily such zero is the root of a trascendental equation, but its approximate location can be derived through a step of Newton's method with starting point $\alpha=\frac{1}{2}$. Considering the Laurent expansion of such approximation at $\beta=+\infty$ we get

$$ \operatorname{argmin} L(\alpha,\beta) \approx \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{12\beta} $$
$$ \min L(\alpha,\beta)\approx \frac{\sqrt{2}}{3\sqrt{\beta}}+\frac{1}{6\beta\sqrt{\beta}} $$

while $R(\beta)\approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{\beta}}+\frac{1}{4\beta\sqrt{\beta}}$, so in the case $\beta\geq 1$ the original inequality holds for a constant that is close (maybe not exactly equal) to $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}$. In the case $\beta\in\left[\frac{1}{2},1\right]$ we may perform a similar analysis, made a bit more cumbersome by the fact that we have to distinguish the cases $\alpha\leq\beta$ and $\alpha\geq \beta$. On the other hand if $\alpha,\beta\in[0,1]$ we have that $|x-\alpha|^{1/2}$ is continuous and non-negative on $[0,1]$, $|x-\beta|^{-1/2}$ has an integrable singularity at $x=\beta$, so it is reasonable that $\text{argmin}L(\alpha,\beta)$ lies pretty close to $\alpha=\beta$, and again we are able to get a bound on *how close* by Newton's method. If $\alpha=\beta$ we have $L(\alpha,\beta)=1$ and $R(\beta)=2(\sqrt{\beta}+\sqrt{1-\beta})\leq 2\sqrt{2} = 2\sqrt{2} L(\alpha,\beta)$, so the original inequality holds for a constant $C$ which is close to $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$.

Putting everything back together:

> There is a positive constant $C$ such that $$
>  \int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{\frac{|x-\alpha|}{|x-\beta|}}\,dx \geq C
>  \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{|x-\beta|}}\,dx $$ holds for any
> $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$.

The value of the optimal constant $C$ is around $\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}$; the exact value can be very hard to get due to the previous issue with the solution of a trascendental equation.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer are very clear and very detailed.